# How to use frontend npms on your project

Tags: node.js, express, npm, frontend, fine-uploader

I'm new to Node.js web development. Just created a project using ExpressGenerator (project structure generator for ExpressJS framework).

The question is: if I want to use FineUploader front-end JS library for my application, which is provided through NPM package, how should I embed it into my project properly? package.json manages server-side dependencies. When authors of front-end module publish it as npm, what approach to further usage they imply? Another package manager like Bower?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `package.json` manages server-side dependencies but not entirely. You can - and should - rely on it to manage front-end dependencies as well.

For that to work you will need a module bundler, to package the node module for the browser. Some of the most popular bundlers for accomplishing this include [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/), [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) among others.

Also note that you can delegate the bundling of node js modules to cdn services such as [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/) or [wzrd](https://wzrd.in/) so that all you need to do to use a node module in your front end code is include a link in your html to the cdn bundled module